# Sumproduct on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba, I want to know how to implement a formula (sumproduct) on excel to vba. The formula gets value from other sheets on the workbook. The formula is:

```
=((SUMPRODUCT(-(Details!$C$7:$C$1182=A3),-(Details!$E$7:$E$1182=B3), -(Details!$S$7:$S$1182="Delivered"), -(Details!$G$7:$G$1182=C3), Details!$N$7:$N$1182)))
```

Here's my code;

```
Private Sub ATO()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim last As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")

last = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("I2:I" & last) = Application.SumProduct(?)

End Sub
```

Is my code on the right track? Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track however if you call an excel function in vba you should use `Application.WorksheetFunction`
For example for your problem `Application.WorksheetFunction.sumif()`
There is one exception, keep in mind that if the same function exists in vba then you can not use the excel version with WorksheetFunction. Therefore if you don't find a function in worksheetfunction then try it without it.
Good luck! If something does not work comment and I will try to help!

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I implement the formula on the vba?

Comment: Btw, my problem is not about sumif, its about sumproduct. My mistake.

Comment: Hmm, I am not really sure I understand you well, if you would like to use a result of a formula like use a suimifs formula's result, then you just do it like I wrote above e.g Application.WorksheetFunction.sumif() however there is a difference when you want to modify the formula of a cell. I think it might be more clear if you read two resources: This is the above mentioned worksheetfunction.sumif documentation from microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193011.aspx But this may be more helpful for you: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/sumif-from-vba/

Comment: I still don't really understand if you want to get the result of the formula in VBA or you want to get the above formula into Excel with VBA. If the letter is true then you should write it as text. Maybe write it in a cell in a spreadsheet and then just reference it in VBA for the other cells.

Comment: I want to get the above formula into Excel with VBA. 

    ws1.Range("I2:I" & last) = Application.SumProduct(('Details'!$C:$C = A),-('Details'!$E:$E=B), -('Details'!$S:$S='Delivered'), -('Details'!$G:$G=C3), 'Details'!$N:$N)

but my code is not working.

Comment: Here's my new code: ws1.Range("I2:I" & last) = Evaluate("SumProduct(-(Details!C = A3), -(Details!E = B3), -(Details!S = 'Delivered'), -(Details!G = C3), Details!N)")
 but it gives error (#value)

Comment: The error was because of the semicolons and no evaluate is needed because you want the formula not the result of the formula, this works I tried: ws1.Range("I2:I" & last).Formula = "=((SUMPRODUCT(-(Details!$C$7:$C$1182=A3),-(Details!$E$7:$E$1182=B3), -(Details!$S$7:$S$1182=" & Chr(34) & "Delivered" & Chr(34) & "), -(Details!$G$7:$G$1182=C3), Details!$N$7:$N$1182)))"

Comment: Thanks but it gives an error(#value) and what's the use of Chr(34)?

Comment: chr(34) is the " and then you don't have to include it in your formula, so excel will be able to use it.

Comment: No problem, btw I think you should just check the formula which is resulted from the macro. Could you paste here the resulting formula? Then I try to check it.

Comment: The resulting formula is this:   =((SUMPRODUCT(-(Details!C:C=A2),-(Details!E:E=B2), -(Details!S:S="Delivered"), -(Details!G:G=C2), Details!$N:$N)))

Comment: I put your formula into I1 just to try it, and it writes 0 for me no value error. (I had to replace your commas to semicolons because of my regional settings, but it is the same) maybe the error is not with the macro anymore, but with the function?